# UFT: GetVisibleText, GetROProperty, GetTextLocation

Tags: vbscript, qtp, uft14

How to use the functions `GetVisibleText` `GetTextLocation` and `GetROProperty`?

I want to identify an object in a Rich Client application using these functions but I didn't find documentation on the net.

Answer (score 1):

- [`GetROProperty`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#GetROProperty) - returns an object's property from the application under test
- [`GetTextLocation`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#OV_Supp_Util/Utility_TextUtil.htm#GetTextLocation) - (on `TextUtil`) can be used to find text on Win32 
  applications
- [`GetVisibleText`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#StdWin/STDPACKAGELib~Window.html#GetVisibleText) - Gets the visible text of a Win32 `Window` object